# How to send and receive ArrayList in intent in Android Annotation

Tags: android-intent, arraylist, android-annotations

I am trying to send and receive ArrayList through intent in Android Annotation. How can I achieve that?

```
 grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                SubcriptionAddPage_.intent(activity).startForResult(REQUEST_CODE);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_in, R.anim.activity_out);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Activity`, you can inject an `Intent` extra like this:

```
@EActivity
public class SubcriptionAddPage extends Activity {

  @Extra
  ArrayList<String> arrayListExtra;

  @AfterInject
  void afterInject() {
    // you can use the injected extra here
  }

}

SubcriptionAddPage_.intent(activity)
  .arrayListExtra(list) // pass the extra to the generated builder
  .startForResult(REQUEST_CODE)
  .withAnimation(R.anim.activity_in, R.anim.activity_out); // you can use this instead of calling overridePendingTransition()
```